# How do I get wireless working again after a reinstall?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I had a normal wired connection to begin with when I originally installed ubuntu, but now I really want to do a reinstall to another partition (just to start fresh). The problem is that I do not currently have the capability to connect in a wired manner, my parents have a server running off of the SINGLE ethernet port on the router, and right now I absolutely don't want to try unplugging it for at least another month. I have wireless on my original installation, the one I'm sending this from, but I have a broadcom card, which ubuntu is infamous for its lack of compatibility with. Both are 32 bit, I have a 64 bit installation that I use when I need it (not all that often) but I mostly use a 32 bit setup. I want to know how I can install the proper drivers offline, along with why in *bloody hell* does ubuntu not have ANY usable drivers included for a type of wireless card that has more or less become the standard for wireless on laptops. It is a BCM43227 card on an acer aspire 7560 laptop with 4 gb of ram.

Comment: The drivers are included but you have to install them because of legal reasons.

Comment: I really don't think this is a duplicate, as it recognizes that there is a simple absence of wireless capability without the drivers, and I am unable to connect in a wired manner to a network, I need a way to install all of the drivers offline.

Comment: The link I gave you tells you how to do both.